# Have a custom TestContextBootstrapper in a meta annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I've a meta-annotation that annotates my test classes:

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@SpringBootTest
@BootstrapWith(MyOwnTestContextBootstrapper.class)
public @interface IntegrationTest {
.....
```

And my test class looks like:

```java
@IntegrationTest
class CreateSubscriptionServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    .......
```

Then I got this exception:
`found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith`
details:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.my.project.CreateSubscriptionServiceTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=com.my.project.MyOwnTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper)]

    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:176)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer.

Replace `@SpringBooTest` with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` so the meta-annotation looks like:

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@BootstrapWith(MyOwnTestContextBootstrapper.class)
public @interface IntegrationTest {
.....
```